# The Napili Template has 2 Contact Support Pages with Different layouts - Why?

Tags: customer-community, community-builder

The Napili Template is showing multiple "Contact Support" pages with the exact same name and URL - BUT they have different layouts. Also, I can't delete either one of them. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Please check your page management to see if it's not custom. I am guessing one is custom built I case.

Comment: PAGE MANAGER: There is a Contact Support Page Under NAPILI PAGES and another one under LOGIN PAGES - but I cannot delete either one.... ??

Comment: Via page manager you will see custom pages and you can delete them by clicking and then selecting delete button

Comment: Hi, I realize this - but this is acting very strange.  I have a list of pages called LOGIN PAGES - and I cannot delete any of them as the delete button is greyed out. There is another issue with this as well - I am using Napili - but I still have the TABS option available under Community Management - Something seems off with this...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. If you are exploring the new Customer Community tools & Templates you can easily change templates from KOA to Napili to Tabs etc. If you create pages using one template and switch to another template you may see the pages created from the other template.

If you mix the above with going into the site.com tools and exploring them by creating templates and pages it can cause all kinds of unwanted behavior.

There doesn't seem to be a valid reason to go into site.com from community builder and (in my mind) it should be removed from being an option when working with community.